# Generate ListDefinition from ListTemplate

Tags: list-definition, list-template

Is there a way or tool to generate list-definition projects/features from an existing list template?

(Sharepoint 2010)

Comment: which version of SP ?

Comment: @SteveB Oh, sorry :) I have improved the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to create a list definition based on existing list definition that comes with SharePoint or installed by other solutions.

I would just use the VS.NET > Add New Item > List Definition and select Custom List as base.
Then locate the existing list template directory in SharePoint root and copy

1)  schema.xml and

2)  element file containing ListTemplate element

Then replace VS.Net’s file with above files. Now you have a list definition which is exact copy of the existing list definition. Now you can change the name, type, base type etc. and claim it as your own list definition!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong you can create site template and then import this template in Visual Studio 2010. When the template is imported, you can choose what elements do you want to include in new solution. You can choose your list. The VS2010 creates all needed files. After this you can simply package this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Designer, you can select a list and click on "Save as template" in the ribbon.

This will create a wsp solution, you can customize as required.